# Strange PHP bug

Tags: php, arrays

When setting a value for an index using a formula to calculate the index, something like 
`$arr[((40.9+0.00004)*100000)] = 1;`,
in the expected result my array should have the value for index as so: `[4090004]=>1`;
instead I got  `[4090003]=>1`.

Can someone please give me an insight into what's going on?

I was able to get around this by casting the index to a string `$arr[(string) ((40.9+0.0004)*100000)] = 1;`, but I would like to understand the underlying mechanics that caused this to happen.

**UPDATE**

This is not directly connected to this question [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) — while the answer might have to do with that floating point bug, I am trying to understand how it effects me here.

Comment: (Incidentally, I get `[4090039]=>1` when I try it.)

Comment: read the Warning here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: @ceejayoz i just edited the formula now you will see what i'm talking about (was supposed to be .00004)

Comment: Your issue remains the same - this is what happens with floating point math.

Comment: @ceejayoz this has nothing to do with math if you `echo 
 ((40.9+0.00004)*100000)` the result is 4090004 it has to do with setting my array  index with a float

Comment: "The results of my floating point math calculation have nothing to do with floating point math" is an... *interesting* assertion.

Comment: (Here, try this and you'll see what's going on: `echo number_format((float) ((40.9+0.00004)*100000), 20);`. On my computer it comes out to `4,090,003.99999999953433871269`.

Comment: i think he is saying the calculation in the array key and not in the array key is different: https://ideone.com/2tlPxj

Comment: @IdontDownVote Chances are internally echoing (and thus casting to string) rounds and the array key truncates. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php indicates "Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8."

Comment: In a nutshell: your number isn't *exactly* 4090004; it will get *rounded* by some operations like casting to a string, and *truncated* (the insignificant bits discarded) by other operations like casting to an integer.